# WooCommerce Add Product Link in Processing Order Email

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I want to add the product link in the Processing Order email which User receives when order. When an order is placed an Order Email sent, I want to get the product link there when user clicks redirects to the detail product page when clicked. Is there any way, I get the product link or the Product Title would Hyperlink.

THANKS

Answer (score 12):

The answer from gunbunnysoulja works great but needs two little updates:

- get_product needs to be wc_get_product
- $_product->id needs to be $_product->get_id()

The updated answer is as follows:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_order_item_name', 'display_product_title_as_link', 10, 2 );
function display_product_title_as_link( $item_name, $item ) {

    $_product = wc_get_product( $item['variation_id'] ? $item['variation_id'] : $item['product_id'] );

    $link = get_permalink( $_product->get_id() );

    return '<a href="'. $link .'"  rel="nofollow">'. $item_name .'</a>';
}
```

Comment: this worked like a charm! Thank you so much for taking time to jump in and share this!!

Answer (score 5):

I am currently using this solution, which I found in the comments on another page. This is not my code.

http://www.vanbodevelops.com/tutorials/add-a-link-back-to-the-order-in-woocommerce-new-order-notifications-email#comment-636

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_order_item_name', 'display_product_title_as_link', 10, 2 );
function display_product_title_as_link( $item_name, $item ) {

$_product = get_product( $item['variation_id'] ? $item['variation_id'] : $item['product_id'] );

$link = get_permalink( $_product->id );

return '<a href="'. $link .'"  rel="nofollow">'. $item_name .'</a>';

}
```

Comment: For those interested, it goes in the functions.php file, not the email template.  I'm wanting to make it share-able on facebook.

Answer (score 1):

To link a product name with its product page in your order emails, open the functions.php file of your child theme and add the following snippet of code:

```html
* Product Links in WooCommerce Order Emails
*/

    add_filter('woocommerce_order_item_name', 'woocommerce_order_item_link', 10, 3);

    function woocommerce_order_item_link( $item_name, $item, $bool ) {
        $url = get_permalink( $item['product_id'] ) ;
        return '<a href="'. $url .'">'.$item_name .'</a>'; 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have been wondering how this works as well. There is little info available anywhere - at least not much with detailed step by step instructions.

The best solution I have came up with is to edit the customer-processing-order.php.

All I did was open it up in a text editor and added a few lines of text to:

"Your order has been received and is now being processed. Your order details are shown below for your reference. Please visit "http://www.youlinkurl".

The end user will have to copy and paste that link unfortunately but at least it works.